# OpenLayers for SVG Images

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, openlayers

For my webpage I want an image that I can navigate with drag-Events and scroll-Events similar to Google-Maps. Instead of implementing it myself, I tried to achieve this with OpenLayers, where I want to use this image instead of a map. I've read about the other examples in stackoverflow, but I am still struggling to understand how to pass the image as first layer.
Currently I try to do the following:

```
testOL(content: string) {
// content is the svg as string
this.map = new Map({
  target: 'imageArea',
  layers: [
    new Image({
      source: new ImageStatic({
        src: content,
      })
    })
  ] ,view : new View({
    center: [0,0],
    zoom: 1
  }) 
})
}
```

The target is simply a div without any content.

I've already tried it by passing an url to a svg as source of the image and I already tried to add a Projection and a view in the map, which all did not work.
I would be happy, if anybody could help me with the issue

Comment: src should be a url.  Try passing the content as a data url  `src: 'data:image/svg+xml,' + encodeURIComponent(content)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`src` is not the correct option name, it should be `url`, and its value should be a data url.  `ImageStatic` also requires the `imageExtent` to be specified in projection coordinates.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v6.4.3/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v6.4.3/build/ol.js"></script>
    <style>
      html, body, .map {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="imageArea" class="map"></div> 
<script>

const content =
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>' +
'<svg' +
'   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"' +
'   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"' +
'   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"' +
'   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"' +
'   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"' +
'   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"' +
'   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"' +
'   width="20"' +
'   height="20"' +
'   version="1.1"' +
'   id="svg6"' +
'   sodipodi:docname="dot.svg"' +
'   inkscape:version="0.92.3 (2405546, 2018-03-11)">' +
'  <metadata' +
'     id="metadata12">' +
'    <rdf:RDF>' +
'      <cc:Work' +
'         rdf:about="">' +
'        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>' +
'        <dc:type' +
'           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />' +
'        <dc:title></dc:title>' +
'      </cc:Work>' +
'    </rdf:RDF>' +
'  </metadata>' +
'  <defs' +
'     id="defs10" />' +
'  <sodipodi:namedview' +
'     pagecolor="#ffffff"' +
'     bordercolor="#666666"' +
'     borderopacity="1"' +
'     objecttolerance="10"' +
'     gridtolerance="10"' +
'     guidetolerance="10"' +
'     inkscape:pageopacity="0"' +
'     inkscape:pageshadow="2"' +
'     inkscape:window-width="1533"' +
'     inkscape:window-height="845"' +
'     id="namedview8"' +
'     showgrid="false"' +
'     inkscape:zoom="11.8"' +
'     inkscape:cx="-35.042373"' +
'     inkscape:cy="11.5"' +
'     inkscape:window-x="67"' +
'     inkscape:window-y="102"' +
'     inkscape:window-maximized="1"' +
'     inkscape:current-layer="g4"' +
'     fit-margin-top="0"' +
'     fit-margin-left="0"' +
'     fit-margin-right="0"' +
'     fit-margin-bottom="0" />' +

'  <g' +
'     id="g4"' +
'     transform="translate(1.5,-1.5)">' +
'    <circle' +
'       style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:3;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"' +
'       id="path822"' +
'       cx="8.5"' +
'       cy="11.5"' +
'       r="8.5"' +
'       inkscape:export-xdpi="400"' +
'       inkscape:export-ydpi="400" />' +
'  </g>' +
'</svg>'

const map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'imageArea',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Image({
      source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
        url: 'data:image/svg+xml,' + encodeURIComponent(content),
        imageExtent: [0, 0, 5e6, 5e6],
      })
    })
  ] ,view : new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 1,
  }) 
});

   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, now it works! Unfortunately I would need the svg-File to keep it's features like clicking on links, which I don't think is possible with a static image. Maybe you know wheter or not there is another possiblity to achieve this with OpenLayers. Still I'll mark this question as accepted, since it solves the above mentioned problem.

Comment: You would need a custom layer render function as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/svg-layer.html  To use that method with a an SVG covering a smaller extent see https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-poitras-i1qyb?file=/main.js

Answer (score 1):

Use an svg string as a point feature style:

```
var svg_string = '<?xml version="1.0" ...><svg>...</svg>'; // your svg content as string
var myStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
      anchor: [16, 48],
      anchorXUnits: 'pixels',
      anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
      src: 'data:image/svg+xml,' + encodeURIComponent(svg_string) // add the encoded svg_string as source
    }),
  });

feature.setStyle(myStyle);
```